# How to differentiate hyperv and azure in virtual machine code?

Tags: azure, hyper-v

I have an Virtual machine that could run both on azure and Hyper-V.

I have some piece of code which should get executed only in azure. But I am not able to identify a way to differentiate azure and Hyper-V.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would prefer to use a configuration attribute in your web.config file. Then you could make two different publish transforms each for Azure and your HyperV environments.

For example, we do something similar with our solutions when relying on AzureStorage and have this in our Web.config in the appSettings section:

`<add key="UseAzureStorage" value="false" />`

Then in the web.config transforms, you would have:

`<add key="UseAzureStorage" value="true" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>`

Also, if you're using Cloud Services in Azure, you could use the RoleRoot environment variable.

http://blog.toddysm.com/2011/03/what-environment-variables-can-you-use-in-windows-azure.html
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557552.aspx

Comment: Hi Ant, Thanks for your reply. I am new to these hyper-visors. I am not aware of web.config file. Is it possible to access this from our VM code?

Comment: I see. I was thinking it was a web application you were working on but perhaps not. Are you using the .NET framework/Visual Studio for your application? You might have an app.config there instead. If you're using Visual Studio, there is an extension called SlowCheetah that can provide the same behavior of config transforms if that's what you're working with at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the question clearly. I have edited it now. Its actually a Virtual machine and I am using C.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I was thinking of an application. In that case, what I mentioned about config transforms doesn't apply here. Would you be able to write a script to see if the system variable, %ROLEROOT% has been set? ROLEROOT is a variable maintained by Azure that represents the root location of the role so if you check and it comes back with a value, you can execute anything Azure-specific.

Comment: Where should I run that script? In my virtual machine(linux) or on the azure?

Comment: I would try running the script from your virtual machine as long as it has access to system variables. From my understanding, it seems like a more centralized place to keep it in case some business requirements change for you.